# How to find a value in one column and replace a value in different column in excel?

Tags: excel

My goal is to find certain value(s) in one column and replace the value of the column next to it.

I think the below example illustrates best what I would like to achieve. I have two columns `ID` and `B` with the following values:

```
ID  B
S1  3
S2  7
S3  2
S4  3
S5  9
S6  2
```

And then I would need to find all the values that are repeated in column `B` and change their `ID` column value to the `ID` number that appeared first. Meaning my end result would be this:

```
ID  B
S1  3
S2  7
S3  2
S1  3
S5  9
S3  2
```

I have no experience with scripts, is it possible to do this without a script?

Comment: If you already have your data entered in your sheet then you can't replace them with a formula, you need to use VBA (macro), there is no formula to change any values out of the cell where it is entered, but if your overwrite your existing data with the formula you'll loose your data. Depending on your task a workaround can be to create a new column where your collect the IDs your need, and maybe manually overwriting the original data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a helper column. Consider the following screenshot:

[image]

The formula in cell C2 is

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(B2,B:B,0))
```

Depending on your data architecture, you may want to copy the results in column C, then use Paste Special > Values to overwrite the initial values in column A and then remove column C. Or you may want to keep column C as a dynamically updating range and refer further dependent formulas to column C instead of column A.